# Black areas in GeoServer ImageMosaic

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic

I've created image mosaic that does not entirely cover its bounding box and got black holes in the places without tif file for that place. I know I can use `OutputTransparentColor: #000000` to make it transparent, but tif files have white color as a background. So either I have transparent color for absentee tif files or transparent color for area just around raster.

[image: Black areas in GeoServer ImageMosaic]

I could set black color as a background for all tifs to make `OutputTransparentColor: #000000` work, but it'll take time. Is there a way to make both these colors transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simple after all. I set `InputTransparentColor` in #FFFFFF and then `OutputTransparentColor` in #000000 and both colors are transparent now.